# Shibboleth 3 - SAML response for Attribute

Tags: shibboleth, saml

I have configured Shibboleth 3 to give the SAML response containing the following Attribute Statement

```
                <saml2:AttributeStatement>
                    <saml2:Attribute FriendlyName="uid"
                        Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                        <saml2:AttributeValue>vinay.joseph@cccc.cccc</saml2:AttributeValue>
                    </saml2:Attribute>
                    <saml2:Attribute FriendlyName="memberOf"
                        Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.42" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                        <saml2:AttributeValue>cccc\cccc-cccc-cccc</saml2:AttributeValue>
                    </saml2:Attribute>
                </saml2:AttributeStatement>
```

I like to if its possible to configure the attribute-resolver.xml so that the following xml Attribute statement is in the SAML response.

```
                <saml2:AttributeStatement>
                    <saml2:Attribute FriendlyName="uid">
                        <saml2:AttributeValue>vinay.joseph@cccc.cccc</saml2:AttributeValue>
                    </saml2:Attribute>
                    <saml2:Attribute FriendlyName="memberOf">
                        <saml2:AttributeValue>cccc\cccc-cccc-cccc</saml2:AttributeValue>
                    </saml2:Attribute>
                </saml2:AttributeStatement>
```

The contents of my attribute-resolver.xml

```
<resolver:AttributeDefinition id="memberOf" xsi:type="ad:Simple" sourceAttributeID="memberOf">
        <resolver:Dependency ref="StaticGroups" />
        <resolver:AttributeEncoder xsi:type="enc:SAML1String" name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:memberOf" encodeType="false" />
        <resolver:AttributeEncoder xsi:type="enc:SAML2String" name="urn:oid:2.5.4.42" friendlyName="memberOf" encodeType="false" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" />
    </resolver:AttributeDefinition>
    <!-- ========================================== -->
    <!--      Data Connectors                       -->
    <!-- ========================================== -->


    <resolver:DataConnector id="StaticGroups" xsi:type="dc:Static" xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:resolver:dc">
         <Attribute id="memberOf">
              <Value>cccc\cccc-cccc-cccc</Value>
         </Attribute>
    </resolver:DataConnector>
```

Answer (score 1):

SAML 2.0 Assertion schema tells that "Name" attribute is required. So you can't do what you want to do.

```
<element name="Attribute" type="saml:AttributeType"/>
<complexType name="AttributeType">
    <sequence>
        <element ref="saml:AttributeValue" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="Name" type="string" use="required"/>
    <attribute name="NameFormat" type="anyURI" use="optional"/>
    <attribute name="FriendlyName" type="string" use="optional"/>
    <anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
</complexType>
```

In first place why do you want that?

https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is not possible. I used to hold for true the `Name` attribute to be the key of the `attribute` tag.

But:

1. have you checked the xml schema if (as I think) Name is a required attribute?
2. in any way, `attribute-resolver` is about fetching attributes. I don't think it's the right place to search the feature you are looking for;
3. can you downgrade to SAML1? Just vaguely remembering the naming rules of attributes were weaker: maybe you can achieve something close to your objective.